# Shopify Liquid: Assign Variant to Quick Add Button

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am attempting to create a quick add button to a product on a custom page template using Shopify liquid. The product has several variants and I would like to assign a specific variant to this product; Namely the second variant.

For the sake of example, let's say my variant ID would be `456`. So, basically, I want to be able to display the product with an id of `123`, shown below. And I want the quick add to be assigned to the variant id `456`. Is there a way to do this using the variant ID? Below is a sample of my loop.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
{%- assign my_products = collections['collection-handle'] -%}
    {%- for product in my_products.products -%}
    {%- if product.id == 123 -%}
        {%- assign product_form_id = 'quick-add-' | append: section_id | append: product.id -%}
        {%- if product.variants.size > 1 -%}
            {%- form 'product', product, id: product_form_id, class: 'actions__form', novalidate: 'novalidate', data-type: 'add-to-cart-form' -%}
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" disabled />

                <button
                    id="{{ product_form_id }}-submit"
                    type="submit"
                    name="add"
                    class="add__button"
                    data-variant_id="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
                    aria-label="Add to cart - {{ product.title | escape }}"
                >
                    <span>Add</span>
                </button>
            {%- endform -%}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I am showing item `123` successfully. However, I'm not sure how or where to assign the variant `456`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your product loop you can get variant like this and filter variant according to their variant id or tags.

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.id == 456 %}
      
    {% else %}
    
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```